# howto get character preceded by a regexpr

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have some code and I want to delete the first occurance of '}' (or the 2nd, doens't matter) after a certain regexpr, using sed or whatever. I don't understand how to point my regexpr to this.

Code I work with looks like this:

```
lore ipsum ^{someWord}} lore ipsum
```

The regexpr I found so far looks like this:

```
\^{[a-zA-z]*}
```

Comment: Use `sed 's/\^{[^{}]*}//g'` if you need a `lore ipsum } lore ipsum` as a result. Or, `sed 's/\^{\{1,\}[^{}]*}\{1,\}//g'` to remove all the `{` at the start and `}`s at the end. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/khLV3s).

Comment: Capture the first part including the first `}` and match the second. Replace with group 1 `echo "lore ipsum ^{someWord}} lore ipsum" | sed -En 's/(\^{[a-zA-Z]*})}/\1/p'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could capture including the first `}` in a group and match the second `}` to be removed. In the replacement use the first capturing group.

*Pattern*

```
(\^\{[a-zA-Z]*\})\}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w7eYJp/1) | [Sed demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RUHXVUG9WF8jJi6mOjpRt8pRNypWK6ZWM6ZWP8ZQX13BxsZGQSknvyhVIbOguDRXIa66OD83NTy/KKW2VgEhrvT/PwA)

*Example*

```
sed -E 's/(\^\{[a-zA-Z]*\})\}/\1/' <<< "lore ipsum ^{someWord}} lore ipsum"
```

*Output*

```
lore ipsum ^{someWord} lore ipsum
```

Note that `[a-zA-z]` [matches more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret) than `[a-zA-Z]`